# Error calling Flask endpoint in AWS EC2 from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, gunicorn

## Summary

I have a flask server spun up with gunicorn that creates an endpoint which I want to call from an AWS lambda function. When I run a test in Lambda however, it returns

```
  "errorMessage": "HTTPConnectionPool(host='<ip_of_ec2>', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/my_project(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7efec823ed60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))",
  "errorType": "ConnectionError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
...
    "  File \"/var/task/requests/adapters.py\", line 516, in send\n    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)\n"
  ]
}
```

What sort of configuration do I need to do in AWS to allow for this call or what am I missing so that the lambda function can make this connection.

## What I have

It should go without saying that everything works locally (I can run curl to call the endpoint on EC2 and make a connection). Lambda and EC2 are on the same vpc and just in case the security group accepts all outbound and inbound traffic.

#### Lambda Function

```
import requests

print('Loading function')
url = 'http://<ip_of_ec2>:8000/api/v1/my_project'


def respond(err, res=None):

    return {
        'statusCode': '400' if err else res.status_code,
        'body': err.message if err else res.json(),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }

def call_project(claim, link):
    return requests.post(url=url, json={"claim": claim, "link": link})


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    operations = {
        'POST': lambda x: call_project(**x)
    }

    operation = event['httpMethod']
    if operation in operations:
        payload = event['queryStringParameters'] if operation == 'GET' else json.loads(event['body'])
        return respond(None, operations[operation](payload))
    else:
        return respond(ValueError('Unsupported method "{}"'.format(operation)))
```

#### Flask Endpoint

```
@app.route('/api/v1/my_project', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_project():
    content = request.get_json()
  ...
    return jsonify(full_pre_json)
```

#### Gunicorn Config

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 1

timeout = 3 * 60  # 3 minutes
```

Comment: `ip_of_ec2` is private or public ip?

Comment: Public I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very easy to implement, but unfortunately very difficult to discover. The error I was getting could be caused by a miss configuration of the VPC, but in my case I simply put in the wrong IP address.

The ip_of_ec2 that I should have been using was the private IP address and not the Public IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring AWS Lambda to have an execution role to interact with the aws resources in the same VPC.

Execution Role:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and sorry it took so long for me to implement it. Unfortunately these links don't seem to help solve the issue. The lambda has the VPC execution role; and the EC2 instance and the lambda are both on the same vpc and security groups. 

Just to confirm that everything was in order with the lambda as well I connected RDS to the same lambda and confirmed that connection works for that.